# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' (Possibly file mishandling)

Tags: python

Trying to decode some RLE text but I'm not sure how to do it via accessing the file, any ideas?

First I tried running the code with manually inputted string, worked fine, but whenever I try to access the file to read it and decode the RLE it doesn't seem to work.

```
def decode(m_str):
    number = ''
    ret_str = ''

    for index in range(len(m_str)):
        try:
            int(m_str[index])
            check = True
        except ValueError:
            check = False

        if check:
            number += m_str[index]
        else:
            ret_str += int(number)*m_str[index]
            number = ''

    return ret_str


f = open("RLE.txt", 'r')
read = f.read()

x = (read)
y = decode(x)
print(y)
```

If the content of the file is `"5S4F8S"` I expect it to output

```
SSSSSFFFFSSSSSSSS
```

Instead, I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: what int do you want "S" to map to?

Comment: are you looking for ord()?

Comment: what does `x = (read)` do... do you want it to be a 2-tuple if so you need `x=(read,)`

Comment: I want "S" to map to the 5, so if x = "5S4F8S" it works fine but when accessing a file it just doesn't work.

Comment: use `print( x )` to see what you try to convert. Maybe you have empty string.

Comment: Added a print(x) between the x and y, tt just prints "5S4F8S" and then goes on to the error

Comment: Just after the `else:` statement, print `number`, what is it?

Comment: also you could directly iterate on `m_str` instead of the indices and access each one. Not an error, just hurts my eyes......

Comment: Just goes downwards like this:

5
4
8

Comment: most text editors add new line at the end so you may have `"5S4F8S\n"` but you will no see `"\n"` on screen but `"\n"` can makes problem in your funtion.

Comment: Also you're not using the full potential of the `try/except`. Instead of assigning a variable and then checking it, simply move your `if` code indise the `try` and the `else` code inside `except`

Answer (score 1):

Put in some basic debugging `print` commands:

def decode(m_str):
    number = ''
    ret_str = ''

```
for index in range(len(m_str)):
    try:
        int(m_str[index])
        check = True
    except ValueError:
        check = False

    print(index, check, number)
    if check:
        number += m_str[index]
    else:
        ret_str += int(number)*m_str[index]
        number = ''

return ret_str


f = open("RLE.txt", 'r')
read = f.read()

x = (read)
print(x, [ord(c) for c in x])
y = decode(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
5S4F8S
 [53, 83, 52, 70, 56, 83, 10]
0 True 
1 False 5
2 True 
3 False 4
4 True 
5 False 8
6 False 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 27, in <module>
    y = decode(x)
  File "so.py", line 16, in decode
    ret_str += int(number)*m_str[index]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Your problem is quite simple: your input includes a non-printing character, such as the "newline" and the end of the input.  That's not a legal item to convert.

To fix this, clean the input:

```
x = (read).strip()
```

This will allow you to get the desired output.

I'll leave the other improvements to you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is perfect!